# Mango Lassi IPA, what do they use to get the lassi flavour?

Tags: recipe

I recently tried a mango lassi IPA which was really nice, it really captured the flavour of the mango lassi. I was wondering what they may have used to get those flavours? Would it be lactose and mango in secondary?

Comment: This sounds delicious. What tastes exactly did you get? Obviously mango, but did you taste any of the spices that typically go into the lassi such as cardamom or cinnamon? Did it have a tangy flavor like the yogurt would provide?

Comment: Yep all of the above

Answer (score 2):

I'm a regular on the BrewTube Official Facebook page and a chap called John Anderson (Abbey Homebrew) uploaded a video to his own Mango Lassi IPA brewday. He used frozen mango that were defrosted and mashed up in the bag and added to the FV. For the body he added Lactose and Maltodextrine during the boil. The Kveik yeast will give a fast ferment but I expect there to be other alternative yeasts that you could use. Perhaps an English Ale Yeast. A link to the brewday video and recipe (in comments) is below.

[Abbey Homebrew - Mango Lassi IPA Brewday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgqzzF8jT7w)

Comment: I would also add just a little bit of cardamom in the tail end of the boil. If you're feeling really adventurous, you could make this a sour to give it the tangy flavor from the yogurt